# strtoupper doesn't work with iconv/utf8_decode and FPDF

Tags: php, utf-8, character-encoding, fpdf

To print special characters to FPDF I can use either:

```
$this->Cell($w2, 15, iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', $text));
```

or

```
$this->Cell($w2, 15, utf8_decode($text));
```

but neither of those work with `strtoupper`. Example:

```
$this->Cell($w2, 15, strtoupper(iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', $text)));
$this->Cell($w2, 15, strtoupper(utf8_decode($text)));

$this->Cell($w2, 15, iconv('UTF-8', 'windows-1252', strtoupper($text)));
$this->Cell($w2, 15, utf8_decode(strtoupper($text)));
```

Given:

```
$text = "Conformità";
```

all of these return:

> CONFORMITà

instead of:

> CONFORMITÀ

### UPDATE

The solutions proposed here or in other answers don't work:

```
mb_strtoupper($text);
mb_strtoupper($text, 'UTF-8');
```

print

> CONFORMITÃ€

Comment: @Jeto, as said in the comment the solution procided by the linked answer doesn't work.

Comment: It seems to [do work](https://3v4l.org/ItWCu) though?

Comment: It probably doesn't work, because your charset is broken - it needs to be set throughout the application, preferably to the same without switching between charsets. I recommend UTF8 if you can use that everywhere. Have a read at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through

Comment: @Qirel, the official FAQ of FPDF state: "Don't use UTF-8" and propose to use those conversion, as far as I understand: http://www.fpdf.org/en/FAQ.php

Comment: @Jeto, it works in PHP *only*. But as I wrote in my question, along with the actual code, it doesn't render in FPDF.

Comment: @Jeto, done. But it was clearly stated in the question. It wasn't a duplicate in my opinion.

Comment: @Mark I voted to reopen.

Comment: @Mark I've tested [this](https://3v4l.org/IK23W) locally and it outputs the correct result. You can try it.

Comment: @Jeto, yep! This seems to be the correct solution!

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the multi-bytes version of the function, `mb_strtoupper()`

```
echo strtoupper($text); //CONFORMITà
echo mb_strtoupper($text); //CONFORMITÀ
```

See PHP documentation : [PHP mb_strtoupper()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mb-strtoupper.php)

Comment: Nope. `mb_strtoupper($text);` or even `mb_strtoupper($text, 'UTF-8');` print `CONFORMITÃ€`. Of course my font contains that character.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following (it worked for me):

```
mb_convert_case($your_string, MB_CASE_UPPER, 'ISO-8859-1');
```